# Transition Header in BIRT?

Tags: report, birt

I've been searching if there is transheader/footer available in BIRT but I can't find any, or similar with transheader. 
Is there any alternative ways to apply transheader/footer on birt?

Answer (score 2):

Incase someone will need this.
I used header and footer in Master page then I added a label. I did my condition in Script: onRender.

Header :

```
if(pageNumber == '1'){
this.text = ''
}else{
this.text= 'continuation...'
}
```

pageNumber is the default current number page in BIRT.